# Faster way of checking if application is running in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm using AppleScript in a program that should be responsive, but it seems like I'm hitting a bottleneck in checking if an app is running, which takes about half a second…is there a way to reduce this?

Here's what I'm doing currently:

```
if application "Finder" is running then
    tell application "Finder" to activate
end if
```

Comment: You could try `do shell script "pgrep -x Finder"` inside a `try` block and if it errors out that will mean Finder is not running.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I am using (in this case for Word), which seems fast enough (less then 0.5 sec). Result is Appli_Launch = true or false :

```
tell application "System Events" to set Appli_Launch to exists (processes where name is "Microsoft Word")
```

Comment: Your statement took less than 0.01 sec running in Script Editor on OSX 10.11.4 on my MBP-15R.

Comment: I found another bottleneck, which seems to be the real culprit of the half-second delay. Thanks for the alternative though! I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a script how I use it. An idea is picked up from @pbell + if statement + python script.

This checks without lag if Mattermost app is running and then resizes its window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def applescript_run():
    script = """
tell application "System Events" to set Mattermost_app_is_running to exists (processes where name is "Mattermost")

if Mattermost_app_is_running then
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Mattermost"
    set position of window 1 to {80, 0}
    set size of window 1 to {1280, 800}
end tell
end if
    """

    p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate(script)

print(applescript_run())
```